# AttributeError: 'Cal' object has no attribute 'area'

Tags: python, python-3.x, program-entry-point

```
class Cal(object):
    pi = 3.142

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

        def area():
            return self.pi * (self.radius**2)


a = Cal(32)
a. area()
```

i get error when i run====
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:/Py Projects/mini/prac.py", line 12, in 
    a. area(32)
AttributeError: 'Cal' object has no attribute 'area'

Comment: You are defining `area` inside the function `__init__`. You need to put it at the top-level of the class. (It also lacks the `self` paramenter.)

Answer (score 1):

You defined the `area()` function *inside* your initializer (`__init__()`) function, which makes it a local function in that scope rather than a method of `Cal`.

Put it outside.

EDIT: you also need to add `self` as an argument for `area()`.

Comment: I think you also need to define it as `area(self)`

Comment: @SvenHarris yes, that's another problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

First, you defined `area()` inside of `__init__()`. That makes `area()` only accessible from there. Make sure you put it at the class level.

On top of that, you haven´t provided the self parameter in `area()`. That way, you are not able to access self it from within the method.

The corrected code would be:

```
class Cal(object):
    pi = 3.142

    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return self.pi * (self.radius**2)


a = Cal(32)
a. area()
```